# dictionaryWithContentsOfFile Returns Nil rather the NSdictionary

Tags: ios

I have created a file named Dict.json .Contents of the file are valid json containg

> {"mydata":[{
>              "A":4,
>              "B":14,
>              "C":7
>              },
>              {
>              "A":4,
>              "B":12,
>              "C":7
>              },
>              {
>              "A":34,
>              "B":154,
>              "C":6
>              },
>              {
>              "A":34,
>              "B":162,
>              "C":6
>              }]}

I want to create a NSDictonary from this file .I tried the following but it returns nil .

> NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Dict" ofType:@"json"];
>   NSMutableDictionary *newArr1=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

I am also checking that file is not nil;

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if (myData) {
    NSLog("There is Data in File !!!!")  
}
```

Comment: Please read the docs for `NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:`.

Comment: @rmaddy reading "NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:" thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the  Documentation

> `+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *path*
>
> A full or relative pathname. The file identified by path must contain a string representation of a ***property list*** whose root object is a dictionary.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A new dictionary that contains the dictionary at path, or nil if there is a file error or if the contents of the file are an invalid representation of a dictionary.

As mentioned above you can only create the dictionary `+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` using plist file not from the .json.

Answer (score 3):

For loading the `json` data you will need `NSJSONSerialization` to fetch `json` data from file

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Dict" ofType:@"json"]; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableDictionary *dic1 = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

Your code only work on `plist` file, not on `json` file.

Comment: Why are you needlessly allocating `dic1` before assigning the result of the deserialization?